# FacebookClient access token is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the below code to show login dialogue of facebook and after successful login it is redirecting to the url which i mentioned.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.client_id = appId;
        parameters.redirect_uri = redirectUrl //Home/CompleteFacebookAuth
        parameters.response_type = "token";
        parameters.display = "popup";
        var fb = new FacebookClient();

        return Redirect(fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters));
}
```

The problem is there in the `CompleteFacebookAuth` action method the token is always null.

```
public ActionResult CompleteFacebookAuth(string token)
{

        var fb = new FacebookClient(token);
        dynamic result = fb.Get("me");

}
```

Any Ideas?

Update: Here is the url

[http://localhost:8399/Home/CompleteFacebookAuth?code=AQBb4tT_n7JPbNqSIVKovkNlKQBTNxpt3sIsPo0wOPyGbuQVHdFCMaH_MqcqosqnwEEso1tclhtGBEgBadxEeUHHtEuKQY2sqiN5LtoIm-JZjp8QlaDxTfQsGMiz4uGA4_Nn4nRX-nW0mIAvGMh-1VET8Hs544he2-DOG0l56ftcsEk9h8rUGNjHwPNT6EbLaFWA74h2dXkiNCwsizqCLnbHuBfaftIzpUPX8DJOBK0nFVD0sVeVR8MLZiGqaa82JhehBTqXVb4uX0tGOxGQCy_Rn88inW2cInled6S18z0ptbLXYl1J92Ne_RP_xZKDunY#*=*](http://localhost:8399/Home/CompleteFacebookAuth?code=AQBb4tT_n7JPbNqSIVKovkNlKQBTNxpt3sIsPo0wOPyGbuQVHdFCMaH_MqcqosqnwEEso1tclhtGBEgBadxEeUHHtEuKQY2sqiN5LtoIm-JZjp8QlaDxTfQsGMiz4uGA4_Nn4nRX-nW0mIAvGMh-1VET8Hs544he2-DOG0l56ftcsEk9h8rUGNjHwPNT6EbLaFWA74h2dXkiNCwsizqCLnbHuBfaftIzpUPX8DJOBK0nFVD0sVeVR8MLZiGqaa82JhehBTqXVb4uX0tGOxGQCy_Rn88inW2cInled6S18z0ptbLXYl1J92Ne_RP_xZKDunY#_=_)

Comment: Could you copy the full url the facebook client return to? Is there any query string in the url?

Comment: @conanak99, See my updates pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is stored in the query string, you just have to change the parameter name of the controller method to map the token. This will work fine.

```
public ActionResult CompleteFacebookAuth(string code)
{

    var fb = new FacebookClient(code);
    dynamic result = fb.Get("me");

}
```

Comment: Code is different from Token. Please read my question once again.